# VMware 1.0.1 Windows7 - Ubuntu hostnames

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, vmware-server, hostname, vmware-vmdk

I'm trying to run Ubuntu as the guest OS using VMWware 1.0.10 with Windows 7 Ultimate as the host OS.

I had this set up previously with Win XP as the host OS and in fact I'm using the same .vmx

My problem is I can't get either Win7 or Ubuntu to be able to ping the other by hostname.

After installing Samba and Winbind on Ubuntu, I was able to get this working when under WinXP, but for some reason I can't get it to work under Win7.

I can ping by IP Address, and the guest OS even shows up by hostname under the Windows networking panel (but of course I can't do anything with it), but pinging using short hostnames just won't work.

Also, Win7 firewall is turned off completely.

Answer (score 1):

The bridge network will not work with Win7 (vmware) at least for now. Try changing the network type for the vm to NAT and It should work.

I have tried also myself to make Win7 Bridge mode work with Vmware 2 and it doesn't either. Let you know later If I figure something out but as far as network try changing the network mode.